# Is it time pattern

Tags: javascript

I've faced the same problem a couple of times lately where I want something to happen on a particular moment in time. For example fire a midi note every quarter time, etc. Usually these get programmed by checking in every iteration of a loop something like this. In an event driven javascript world this would look like this:

```
on('tick', check);

function check(time) {
  if (is_it_time(time)) {
     do_your_thing();
  }
}
```

Of course this if test gets executed way more often than is actually needed. I'm sure this is a common problem and I'm looking for a pattern or pointers to theory on this problem.

Edit: Should point out that this has nothing to do with actual time. The ticks I am receiving come not from the javascript real time clock. Maybe it would be interesting to hear how setTimeOut works under the hood. I can't imagine there is a if test every millisecond.

Edit2: The best thing I've come up with so far is hold a queue of functions for every every tick and cycle through them.

```
var tasks = new Array(96);

function check(ticks) {
   tasks[ticks].forEach(function(task) { 
      task(); 
   });
}
```

Since the number of tasks could grow large this is the most efficient I think.

Comment: Eh, use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) or [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)?

Comment: what about setTimeout() ? Does it suit you ?

Comment: No, I am aware of setTimeout. What I want is to implement my own setTimeout based on an external clock source. This clock would ticking every time a tick event is encountered. That's what you should understand from the code example I included

Comment: I dont think there are any patterns. Any plugin or any other implementation will have some function which will be called every second.

Comment: If your clock is disconnected from the real time clock, then there is no way to know how to translate "at midnight" into ticks. If it is synchronised with real time clock, then it is likely useless. In any case, you need to explain your question in more detail.

Comment: @KremnevSergey nah, a calculated setTimeout is just fine in this case. See Amadan's answer.

Comment: The question is, what's so special about this external clock source that makes it incompatible with JS timers? Without knowing that it's impossible to answer.

Comment: Maybe I should have excluded the actual time examples but the thing I'm facing right now is a midi clock. It sends out 96 ticks per measure and can slow down and up.

Comment: If you want a solution to your actual problem, it's usually best to show an example that replicates that problem. Otherwise this is way too broad to get any useful answers as you probably already noticed.

Comment: Yes, you should have. There is nothing relevant about "run script at midnight, ring alarm at 6am" against MIDI events. This is a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). To answer your update - if you need tick events, then there is no solution that does not involve calling a function on every tick; so definitely not "way more than is actually needed".

Answer (score 1):

```
function runAt(time, task) {
  var now = new Date();
  var delay = time - now;
  return setTimeout(task, delay);
}

runAt(Date.parse("2015-05-29T00:00:00+00:00"), function() {
  console.log("yo");
});
```